Modelling population growth where only the latest generation divides at a point in time
I'm trying to come up with a continuous function to model the growth of a bacterial population under the following conditions.

Bacteria never die

Each bacterium divides to produce two offspring

Each bacterium divides only once in its lifetime


I.e. - it's a dividing population, but not a classical exponential because only the latest generation divides at a point in time.
So for example, if the population starts with $2$ bacteria, it will follow the pattern:
$$\begin{align}
2& \qquad \text{at} \qquad t=0 \\
6& \qquad \text{at} \qquad t=1 \\ 
14& \qquad \text{at} \qquad t=2 \\
30& \qquad \text{at} \qquad t=3.
\end{align}$$
I assume the solution involves an exponential function or a sum of exponential functions, but my various attempts with guesses, integrals and differential equations haven't worked.
Please suggest a suitable continuous function for this scenario and explain the reasoning behind it.

You might do well to count the number of splitable and unsplittable bacteria at each time point, such as $(2,0)$ at $t=0$, $(4,2)$ at $t=1$, $(8,6)$ at $t=2$, $(16,14)$ at $t=3$ etc.  The patterns may then be obvious and easily provable.

Also, unless the two initial bacteria interact with each other in any way (or their descendants interact), I'd start with just one; it might make the development easier to see.

Let $a_n$ represent the number of bacteria present at time $n$. We want to find a recursion relation for $a_n$ in terms the number of bacteria present in the previous two iterations, i.e. in terms of $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$, with the boundary conditions that $a_0$ is given, and that $a_1 = 3 a_0$ is also given.
At step $n$, the number of bacteria which constitute the most recent generation is $a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$. This portion of the population gets multiplied by $3$. Since the number of bacteria $a_{n-2}$ from all previous generations is also present, we are left with the recursion relation
\begin{equation}
a_n \;=\; 3(a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}) + a_{n-2} \;=\; 3a_{n-1} - 2a_{n-2} \qquad\qquad (1)
\end{equation}
Linear recursion relations such as Eq. (1) succumb to power law solutions, so we guess an answer of the form $a_n = r^n$. Substituting this guess into (1) and dividing through by $r^{n-2}$, we are left with
\begin{equation}
r^2 \;=\; 3r - 2\, ,
\end{equation}
which has solutions $r = 1$ and $r=2$. Thus (1) has the general solution
\begin{equation}
a_n \;=\; A + B\cdot 2^n\, ,
\end{equation}
where the unknown coefficients $A$ and $B$ can be determined by applying the boundary conditions:
\begin{align}
a_0 &\;=\; A + B\\
a_1 &\;=\; 3a_0 \;=\; A+B\cdot2^1
\end{align}
Solving these yields $A = -a_0$ and $B = 2a_0$, and we are left with:
\begin{equation}
a_n \;=\; a_0\left(2^{n+1}-1\right)
\end{equation}
Plugging in $a_0 = 2$ does indeed recover your example sequence $2$, $6$, $14$, $30$, ...
